# Flutter: Best Practices of Calling Async Code from UI

Tags: async-await, dart, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app but wondering what should I do when calling async code from UI - let's say the build method of a UI widget.

For example, my app connects Firebase through a service class, which uses Async-Await style to grab records from Firebase. Using await ensures my service class's method will complete records retrieval before returning to the UI side.

However, since the service class's method is marked as async, it returns a Future immediately to the calling UI widget and the UI code keeps running, before the service class's method is completed.

Yes I can write codes for the "then()" callback to handle the retrieved records, but what about other codes inside the widget that follow, and depend on the result of the async call? Does it mean I need to embed everything inside the "then()" clause and avoid adding any execution steps after a method call that returns a Future? Any suggested pattern for such usage model?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   RealtimeDatabase.getData()  // my service class
      .then((onValue) {
        ..... // do something after the async call is completed
   }

   ..... // do something immediately before the async call is done


class RealtimeDatabase {

    Future<String> getData() async {

    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().orderByKey().once(); // will wait until completed
    .....
    .....
```

Sorry if my description here is lack of clarity, any advice is much welcome.

Jimmy

Comment: Ideally have a variable `isLoading = true`, return a loading widget when true. In the `then` block call `setState` with `isLoading` false.

Comment: @Hemanth sounds good!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Flutter there are widgets that can help you do this seamlessly (e.g, [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) , [`StreamBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)) and you can control what to be rendered based on their resolution.

Example on `FutureBuilder`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("node"),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData? new Scaffold(
          ///start building your widget tree
          ):new CircularProgressIndicator(); ///load until snapshot.hasData resolves to true
},);
  }
```

Example for `StreamBuilder`:

```
class Database {

  DatabaseReference _refProfile = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
      "profiles");

  getProfiles() => _refProfile.onValue; }
```

.............

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new StreamBuilder<Event>(
          stream: _database.getProfiles(), //_database = new Database()
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
          return event.hasData?new Scaffold(

///build your widget tree
                    ):new CircularProgressIndicator();

/// place holder
}
```

**It is worth mentioning that**

`FutureBuilder` is better used when you want to *fetch* some data *once* and do not care of having consistent connection or tracking any changes in the data.

While `StreamBuilder` , on the other hand, enables you to keep listening to the data and you can update the state of the UI according to any update in the data.

Comment: Great!! This is what I looking for!!

Comment: I have edited the answer to include an example for StreamBuilder as well, and the links for the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've struggled for few days and didn't aware Flutter have such nice features!

Comment: Seems like a return statement is missing the StreamBuilder example.
My wondering is what happens at the place of the "Build your widget tree" comment. For instance, how is it supposed to show the yielded by the stream profiles in a ListView...

Comment: @aziza: BTW I tried the FutureBuilder that returns a Scaffold with a ProgressIndicator embedded while loading data, looks very good except that I want the empty Scaffold to replaces the original Scaffold at the exact same position - swapping the existing one temporarily, therefore the top level widgets will not be hidden.

How to do that?

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov thank you for pointing out about the return. You can replace the comment for example with `return new Text(event.data.snapshot.value.toString)` will give you a Text with your data.

Comment: @Wonderjimmy this is my bad, I should have been clearer, you would never want to do FutureBuilder on Scaffold level, instead do it in the body property. This way your appbar, drawer, FAB, tabs..etc will load normally and only the body with the content will load.

Comment: @aziza Thanks for your info! How about if I use FutureBuilder for changing application route? Let's say I check a remote source for authentication, if success I use Navigator.pushNamed to route to the home screen. However since Navigator returns a Future instead of widget, is it appropriate using FutureBuilder in this way?

Comment: Hmmm, unless I see your code of handling this I can not really judge. However, the basic idea is you need to compose your views in different classes, and you can do something similar to this `return user.hasData? new HomeScreen():new LoginScreen(),` then in your login screen you have the sign in method/s that get triggered on button click and only navigate the user to HomeScreen() when the method resolve to a desired outcome, otherwise handle the errors/exceptions.

Comment: @aziza Finally I refactored my app that the authentication and routing logic is moved into another widget, then the login FutureBuilder can simply return another MaterialApp widget that is the core app itself; the code looks much better now :D

Answer (score 3):

While I think the methods mentioned by @aziza are definitely the way to go, it's worth noting that you can "roll your own" as well.

So, for example, in `initState()`, you could do something like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myItems = // some sane default
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("node")
      .then((items) {
        if (widget.mounted) setState(() { _myItems = items; }
      });
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
   ///start building your widget tree
  );
}
```

It'd be preferable to use `FutureBuilder` here, but this is another way to do it (even if it's not necessarily a best practice).

Comment: Hi Dan, in your solution is the build method being called twice? One when _myItems is null, and the second time is after setState is called?

But during rebuild, will initState being called again?

Comment: initState only gets called first time the widget is added to the tree.  But yes, build will get called twice in this example, once during the initialization of state, once after the future resolves.

Comment: initState is not desirable as when you get back to old screen, sometimes, we need to call API, for this, FutureBuilder is best approach.