# Passing Future as parameter to another class

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to pass Future to a dialog helper class, I'm trying to show a dialog when user fails to load, and when user clicks on retry the app will launch the network call again

**Passing in future into dialog class**

```
void getCountryApi() async {

    GlobalService globalService = new GlobalService();

    ...

    //wait for future to be finished
    bool isSuccessful =
        await globalService.requestApi(CountryApi, queryParameters, context);
    if (isSuccessful) {
      dialogManager.information2(context, 'Success', globalService.fullData);
    } else {
      //dialogManager.information2(context, 'Success', globalService.fullData);
      dialogManager.retryDialog(context, 'Failed', globalService.fullData,globalService.requestApi(CountryApi, queryParameters, context));
    }
  }
```

**Dialog helper class**

```
retryDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String description, Future apiCall) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () {},
            child: AlertDialog(
              title: Text(title),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(description),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          onPressed: () async {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            await apiCall;
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Retry',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),                    
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that, the future object perform a network call immediately in this line

```
dialogManager.retryDialog(context, 'Failed', globalService.fullData,globalService.requestApi(CountryApi, queryParameters, context));
```

which is before the user click on retry button

Comment: You can pass a Future the same as you can pass any other data type. You're going to have to be more specific if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi @Abion47, thanks for replying, problem with my current approach is that whenever I pass the future into the dialog class, the future runs immediately before onpress is called

Comment: It's unclear what Future you are referring to and where you are passing it to the dialog class.

Comment: Im trying to pass in the Future 'await globalService.requestApi', its an future, I tried passing it as an function into the ' dialogManager.retryDialog' helper class, the retry dialog takes in 3 params and i'm attempting to pass the Future/Function as one of the param, but it won't work because it's an async function, passing it as an Future causes it to launch instantly before the dialog is even rendered.

Comment: `globalService.requestApi` is the future. By `await`ing it, you are choosing to instead wait for the future to complete and store the result (which is a `bool` in this case). If you want to work with the future itself, remove the `await`.

Comment: One confusing thing though, the way you use the future in the dialog is in the button handler where you do `Navigator.pop(context);` and _then_ await the future, after which nothing happens as that's the end of the function.

Comment: Ah yes!
That fixed the problem, thank you @Abion47!
I got confused with the await, after i removed the await and pass in getCountryApi() function instead of globalService.requestApi, things are working!

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology is not correct, on success or failure you need to show only alert dialogue and on alert button mentioned all the API call.

Comment: Yes, now Im trying to pass the API call into the dialog box's onpress button, but im not sure how should I pass it.
I tried passing it as an function but it won't work because it's an async function, passing it as an Future causes it to launch instantly before the dialog is even rendered.

Comment: You can call a async function from UI by using this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135632/flutter-best-practices-of-calling-async-codes-from-ui).

Comment: I see, i was trying to build a general dialog helper to handle my network success/fail, but i'll give the stream builder a try, thanks!